# Use Power Automate to get access to File without access to the root sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

**Issue**

I'm working on automating the pull of items off of MS Teams using Power Automate. Using get file has been perfect until this scenario.

There is a team called Compliance. We were not added to the team, rather someone used the website to share a specific folder with us. Analytics.

In the section of `Site Address`, Power Automate will automatically trim the URL. However, as I stated, I don't have access to the root URL. What I do have access to for example is:
`https://OrgName.sharepoint.com/sites/compliance/Shared%20Documents`

When I put that into Power Automate in the `Site Address` section, I'm getting a URL of just `https://OrgName.sharepoint.com/sites/compliance`. For the path of the folder `File Identifier`, it won't return the folder structure and instead I get this message:
[image]

Again, I do have access to the URL when the `/Shared%20Documents` portion of the URL is there. I thought that error made sense as I don't have access to the site hyperlink. I assumed I'd be able to just get the path right, and everything would run. But all I'm getting as a result is:

[image]

**Things I've Tried**

I've tried entering the URL manually, having it auto generated, and even storing it in a variable. In all cases the URL in the back end code gets trimmed.

I've tried multiple file paths, in all cases no matter which file path I use, I get the error `Route did not match`. I've referenced other code that is running successfully (I have access to the root sharepoint in those cases) and sometimes the path needs to contain `/Shared Documents/General/Analytics/File.xlsx` or `/Shared Documents/Documents/Channel Name/Analytics/File.xlsx`.

I've attempted obtaining the "ID" of the file from Microsoft Graph, but I was never successful in running a Graph query to get it.

I've used the information bubble in both Teams and Sharepoint Online to get the file path, and the share/download links to get the file path, and they all return `Route did not match`.

**Goal**

The goal is to be able to use power automate to pull information from a file without being granted access to the root system. Again, the hyperlinks to file work just fine, but setting up power automate has been a nightmare. Is this possible or are there any workarounds we might be able to use?